# PayPal Adaptive Payments - background processing

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the PayPal Classic API for Java and Adaptive Payments. It's a Tomcat web app.

I am getting a PreApproval from the user up front through the web interface. Once their request is accepted on the back-end, I am processing the payment with PAY in Java. i.e. not in a servlet. It works fine but complains if I do not have the CancelUrl or ReturnUrl defined and valid.

Since I am processing the payment in a non-web environment, there is no valid URL and those two options should never be required.

Am I missing something? Should I just include a couple of URLs and ignore the fact that it makes no sense?

What is the best way to automatically transact preapproved funds based on a status field changing in the database?

```
PayRequest payreq = new PayRequest();
payreq.setCancelUrl(hostURL + "/whydoineedthis.do?&action=cancel");
payreq.setReturnUrl(hostURL + "/whydoineedthis.do?&action=approved");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are required for the server to accept your request, but as you said, when sending Pay requests with a preapproval key there really is no need for it.  I generally just use the primary site domain, like www.domain.com in both places.